# how to create new instance of PIXI.texture

Tags: canvas, pixi.js

I'm using PIXI to create sprites from sprite-sheet images and I'm trying to animate them by changing the position of texture frame:

```
  // creating new instance of PXI.texure
  var texture = new PIXI.Texture.fromImage('my-start-frame-name');
  // creating sprite
  var runner = new PIXI.Sprite(texture);


  // this is the frame I'm using to change the picture in sprite sheet
  var frame = new PIXI.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);

  // animating the sprite
  var interval = setInterval(function () {
    // moving frame one unit to right
    frame.position.x += 100;
    runner.texture.frame = frame;

    //  ending animation
    if (frame.position.x == 1000) {
       frame.position.x = 0;
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 50);
```

The problem is when I create multiple sprites from a single sprite sheet, all textures are equal:

```
texture1 == texture2; // true
```

and thus animating all sprites together.

**Note:** *If I use different sprite sheet images for different sprites, all sprites animate separately, which is what I expect.*

Comment: I've mentioned this to you before but is there a reason you are trying to manually create an animation instead of using a PIXI MovieClip?? It is built for exactly this purpose. You pass in a list of frames and it automatically renders the animation for you. Save yourself the trouble.

Comment: @Karmacon no, there is no reason not to use movieClip. Seems I just missed your comment and I saw it now. I'm gonna read its docs to change my animations to movieClip right now. Thank you veeeery much!

Comment: This example should have everything you need http://pixijs.github.io/examples/index.html?s=demos&f=movieclip-demo.js&title=MovieClip

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably here `runner.texture.frame = frame`. As `runner` is already a *texture instance* you want to change the frame of that instance, not of the *original texture* (i.e. `texture`).

Changing to this should solve the issue: `runner.frame = frame`.

[Here](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/6419-brain-fart-multiple-frames-from-the-same-image/) a similar thread